# When is it necessary to increase $N$ when $\epsilon$ decreases for Cauchy sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

My intuition Cauchy (or convergent) sequences is that the **smaller** we make $\epsilon$ **the further down** the sequence we (might?) need to go to make that true. However, in the definition of Cauchy this is not a requirement and I am trying to understand why its not (and fix this intuition if its wrong and adjust it to the right in intuition since this seems an important conceptual detail about Cauchy sequences).

Recall the definition of a Cauchy sequence $(p_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$:

$$ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_{\epsilon} : n_{\epsilon},m_{\epsilon} \geq N_{\epsilon} \implies d( p_{ n_{\epsilon} },p_{ m_{\epsilon}} ) < \epsilon$$

in plain English it says that for every accuracy epsilon we require, after some point in the sequence $N_{\epsilon}$ every pair of points are bounded within some (open) ball of radius $\epsilon$.

Consider $0<\epsilon_2<\epsilon_1$ (decreasing epsilon). To my understanding there are only **two cases** to consider:

1) When $N_{\epsilon_1}$ is already so far down the sequence that $\epsilon_1$ is actually to large so $d(p,q) < \epsilon_2 < \epsilon_1$

2) Or that $N_{\epsilon_1}$ is of non-trivial size and there are actually some elements $n_{\epsilon_1},m_{\epsilon_1} \geq N_{\epsilon_1}$ between $0<\epsilon_2< d( p_{ n_{\epsilon_1} },p_{ m_{\epsilon_1}} ) < \epsilon_1$.

In case 1) $N_{\epsilon_1}$ can be set to $N_{\epsilon_2}$ because for $n,m \geq N_{\epsilon_1} = N_{\epsilon_2}$ we have $d(p,q) < \epsilon_2 < \epsilon_1$ which is what we required (if we know $N_{\epsilon_1}$ of course). So we **do not** need to increase $N$ in this case.

In case 2) we first note that its impossible for **all** the terms $n_,m \geq N_{\epsilon_1}$ to be between $0<\epsilon_2< d( p_{ n_{\epsilon_1} },p_{ m_{\epsilon_1}} ) < \epsilon_1$. If this were the case then the sequence wouldn't be Cauchy because there would be some epsilon (namely $\epsilon_2$) such that its impossible to find an $N$ s.t. they are all less than $\epsilon_2$. Namely they all get stuck at a distance at least $\epsilon_2$ but we require to be able to always find an $N$ for which their distance is at most some positive constant (which we showed its impossible for $N_{\epsilon}$). Ok if this is not the case then we call $E$ the pair of elements of the sequence such stuck in that interval $(\epsilon_2,\epsilon_1)$ i.e.

$$ E = \{ (p,q) \in (p_n)^{\infty}_{n=N_{\epsilon_1}} \mid \epsilon_2 < d(p,q) < \epsilon_1 \}$$

this set must be **finite**. If it weren't then it would have all the elements of the sequence and again it would imply the sequence is not Cauchy again. Now consider going through all the elements of $E$ and collecting their indices in the set $I$. $I$ must also be finite. Thus it must have a maximum $M = \max I$. Now let:

$$ N^* = M+1 = \max I + 1$$

note $N^*$ is defined to be the index of an element of the sequence such that when compared to any other element its not in the interval $(\epsilon_2,\epsilon_1)$. This element (and its index) must exist. If it didn't then $d(p_{N^*},q) $ would be in $(\epsilon_2,\epsilon_1)$. This can't be true because if it were in $I$ then $N^*$ would be larger than $M$ but $M$ wouldn't be the max (but its defined to be the maximum index from $E$). Therefore, $N^*$ must not be in $I$ and thus we can set $N^* = N_{\epsilon_2}$. Which shows that if $\epsilon_2$ is smaller than $\epsilon_1$ then unless $\epsilon_1$ is too larger, we **will** need to go down the sequence to get a new more meaningful $N$ if the sequence is Cauchy.

---

If possible I'd love to know if my proof is correct of course.

Comment: Your intuition seems good. There's just no need for this extra stipulation in the definition. For example, a constant sequence is Cauchy, and $N_\epsilon = 1$ would work for any $\epsilon$.

Comment: @NathanielMayer that I believe is caught by case 1 I outlined in my proof I believe...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not disagreeing with you at all. You seem to know what's going on. What is your question?

Comment: @NathanielMayer my question is if the proof is correct, I just wasn't sure. Good to know I'm not delusional! :D

Comment: Proof of what? What's the proposition?

Comment: @NathanielMayer when its necessary to increase $N$ when $\epsilon$ decreases.

Comment: @NathanielMayer perhaps: "If a Cauchy sequence happens to be constant from some point onwards, you can keep N fixed at that point and decrease ϵ freely without having to increase N any further.

If that’s not the case, then smaller values of ϵ would force you to increase N."